# В чем может быть проблема? Ошибка: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format

Tags: android, unity3d, сборка, apk

Ошибка возниrает при попытке сделать сборку .apk не при помощи системы Gradle. Полный текст ошибки:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/JohnWhite1221/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/ads/BuildConfig;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/ads/IUnityAdsListener;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/ads/UnityAds;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$1;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$2;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$FinishState;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$PlacementState;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$UnityAdsError;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/ads/adunit/AdUnitActivity;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
    ... 9 more
]
stdout[
processing archive C:\Users\JohnWhite1221\Documents\GameWorkbench\Sushi hero R\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityAds\libs\.\classes.jar...
processing com/unity3d/ads/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/IUnityAdsListener.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$FinishState.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$PlacementState.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$UnityAdsError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/adunit/AdUnitActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/adunit/AdUnitError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/adunit/AdUnitEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/adunit/AdUnitOpen.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/adunit/AdUnitSoftwareActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit$4.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit$5.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Broadcast.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Cache.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Cache$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Connectivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/DeviceInfo.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/DeviceInfo$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/DeviceInfo$StorageType.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Intent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Intent$IntentError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Lifecycle.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener$4.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener$5.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener$6.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Placement.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Request.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Request$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Request$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Request$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Resolve.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Resolve$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Sdk.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Storage.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$4.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$5.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$6.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/broadcast/BroadcastError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/broadcast/BroadcastEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/broadcast/BroadcastEventReceiver.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/broadcast/BroadcastMonitor.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheDirectory.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheThread.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheThreadHandler.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheThreadHandler$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/Configuration.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/ConfigurationFailure.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/EnvironmentCheck.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeState.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateAdBlockerCheck.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateAdBlockerCheck$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateAdBlockerCheck$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateComplete.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateConfig.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateCreate.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateError$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateLoadCache.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateLoadWeb.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateNetworkError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateReset.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateReset$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateRetry.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/connectivity/ConnectivityChangeReceiver.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/connectivity/ConnectivityEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/connectivity/ConnectivityMonitor.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/connectivity/ConnectivityMonitor$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/connectivity/ConnectivityNetworkCallback.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/connectivity/IConnectivityListener.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/AdvertisingId.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/AdvertisingId$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/AdvertisingId$GoogleAdvertisingInfo.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/AdvertisingId$GoogleAdvertisingInfo$GoogleAdvertisingInfoBinder.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/AdvertisingId$GoogleAdvertisingInfo$GoogleAdvertisingInfoBinder$GoogleAdvertisingInfoImplementation.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/AdvertisingId$GoogleAdvertisingServiceConnection.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/Device.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/Device$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/Device$MemoryInfoType.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/DeviceError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/Storage.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/StorageError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/StorageEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/StorageManager.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/device/StorageManager$StorageType.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/lifecycle/LifecycleError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/lifecycle/LifecycleEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/lifecycle/LifecycleListener.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/log/DeviceLog.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/log/DeviceLog$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/log/DeviceLog$UnityAdsLogLevel.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/log/DeviceLogEntry.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/log/DeviceLogLevel.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/mediation/IUnityAdsExtendedListener.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/metadata/InAppPurchaseMetaData.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/metadata/MediationMetaData.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/metadata/MetaData.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/metadata/PlayerMetaData.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/misc/Utilities.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/misc/ViewUtilities.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/placement/Placement.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/properties/ClientProperties.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/properties/SdkProperties.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/IResolveHostListener.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/IWebRequestListener.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/IWebRequestProgressListener.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/NetworkIOException.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/ResolveHostError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/ResolveHostEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/WebRequest.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/WebRequest$RequestType.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/WebRequestError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/WebRequestEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/WebRequestHandler.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/WebRequestResultReceiver.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/WebRequestThread.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/WebRequestThread$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/request/WebRequestThread$1$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/video/VideoPlayerError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/video/VideoPlayerEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/video/VideoPlayerView.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/video/VideoPlayerView$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/video/VideoPlayerView$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/video/VideoPlayerView$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/video/VideoPlayerView$4.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/video/VideoPlayerView$5.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/video/VideoPlayerView$6.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/WebView.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/WebView$JavaScriptInvocation.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/WebViewApp.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/WebViewApp$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/WebViewApp$WebAppChromeClient.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/WebViewApp$WebAppClient.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/WebViewEventCategory.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/bridge/CallbackStatus.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/bridge/Invocation.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/bridge/NativeCallback.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/bridge/WebViewBridge.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/bridge/WebViewBridgeError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/bridge/WebViewBridgeInterface.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/bridge/WebViewCallback.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/bridge/WebViewCallback$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/webview/bridge/WebViewExposed.class...
processing archive C:\Users\JohnWhite1221\Documents\GameWorkbench\Sushi hero R\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-ads\libs\.\classes.jar...
processing com/unity3d/ads/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/IUnityAdsListener.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$FinishState.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$PlacementState.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/UnityAds$UnityAdsError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/adunit/AdUnitActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/adunit/AdUnitError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/adunit/AdUnitEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/adunit/AdUnitOpen.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/adunit/AdUnitSoftwareActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit$4.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/AdUnit$5.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Broadcast.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Cache.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Cache$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Connectivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/DeviceInfo.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/DeviceInfo$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/DeviceInfo$StorageType.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Intent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Intent$IntentError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener$4.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Listener$5.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Placement.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Request.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Request$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Request$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Request$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Resolve.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Resolve$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Sdk.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/Storage.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$4.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$5.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/api/VideoPlayer$6.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/broadcast/BroadcastError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/broadcast/BroadcastEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/broadcast/BroadcastEventReceiver.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/broadcast/BroadcastMonitor.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheDirectory.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheError.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheEvent.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheThread.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheThreadHandler.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/cache/CacheThreadHandler$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/Configuration.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/ConfigurationFailure.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/EnvironmentCheck.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeState.class...
processing com/unity3d/ads/configuration/InitializeThread$InitializeStateAdBlockerCheck.class...
pro<message truncated>
```

Answer (score 0):

Повторное добавление классов, которые уже существуют в сборке, в частности "**unity3d/ads**". Скорей всего у вас в разных **jar** повторяются классы.